# android eclipse are two hit state xml files needed in md and hd drawable folders

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, image

I know in order to design for android devices you can make 2 images named the same thing with different resolutions and put them in the md and hd drawable folders.  Android will call the correct version based on the devices screen density.

My question is this:  If I have an xml file that defines a clickable image like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/listitemorange" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/orange_click" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/listitemorange" />
</selector>
```

**I have the listitemorange and the orange_click images in both the md and hd folders, but do I need to have a copy of the xml file itself in both folders, or can I just keep in it in the md folder and it will still know to call the hd images when on an hd screen?**

Please let me know if that doesn't make sense... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put the xml in the drawable folder, and the image in drawable-md&drawable-hd, everything will be okay.

Comment: Just as I thought.  Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

> but do I need to have a copy of the xml file itself in both folders, or can I just keep in it in the md folder and it will still know to call the hd images when on an hd screen?

As far as I understand it, you can just put one copy of that xml in the mdpi folder and Android will use it even when the device is hdpi. In other words, it will look for resources in the mdpi folder if it can't find them in the hdpi folder.

See... [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

**EDIT:** This paragraph at the end of the 'Using configuration qualifers' effectively covers it.

> Be aware that, when the Android system picks which resources to use at runtime, it uses certain logic to determing the "best matching" resources. That is, the qualifiers you use don't have to exactly match the current screen configuration in all cases in order for the system to use them. Specifically, when selecting resources based on the size qualifiers, the system will use resources designed for a screen smaller than the current screen if there are no resources that better match (for example, a large-size screen will use normal-size screen resources if necessary). However, if the only available resources are larger than the current screen, the system will not use them and your application will crash if no other resources match the device configuration (for example, if all layout resources are tagged with the xlarge qualifier, but the device is a normal-size screen).

The answer from silentnuke is correct in your case if you're only providing density-specific resources for hdpi and mdpi. Be aware that if you also provide resources for ldpi, the logic will fall through to the drawable-ldpi folder before checking the default drawable folder.

I tend to either use only the default folders or, if I'm catering for device density, only the density-specific folders and avoid using both approaches. Just my preference and way of working.

Comment: I've read the site many times, but it didn't explicitly have my situation in it.  But thank you for the confirmation

Comment: @Nick: I've quoted the text from that page which explains the mechanisms at work just for reference.